# How can I apply loop to retrieve the required data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from the following collection "Buses" **if**  say *Bus_Driver=="xyz"*.

My Firebase test looks like this:

[image]

I am getting database reference with this code:

```
 busInfoReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Buses");
```

The following loop I've applied does not work correctly:

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            busInfo = ds.getValue(BusInforamtion.class);
            if(ds.exists()) {
                if(busInfo.getBus_Driver().equalsIgnoreCase(driverName))
                {
                    saveData()

                    break;
                    //}
                }
            }
```

How can I apply loop to get the required data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: then just check simple refrence.equalto(name) and trigger action.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need query your database like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Buses").orderByChild("Bus_Driver").equalsTo("xyz");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String Bus_Driver = ds.child("Bus_Driver").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, Bus_Driver);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will contain all bus driver names.